# Docker with cloudflare

Tags: ssl, docker, https, digital-ocean, cloudflare

Good morning!

I use docker as a development platform, I have an APP and want to use https protocol to maintain the most reliable connection, thinking this way, I decided to use the Cloudflare that besides free ssl provide some tools to improve customer connection to the App .

However, after enabling ssl in cloudflare, lose access to the database and phpmyadmin.

Sorry for bad english

help?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using Flexible SSL, when using Flexible SSL Cloudflare communicates between itself and origin webserver using HTTP (whilst using HTTPS for the end user).

Cloudflare communicates it uses HTTPS on the front-end to the origin using an `X-Forwarded-For` header, by installing an Apache extension called [Mod_Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/) you can ensure your web server takes account of this whilst using HTTPS (therefore ensuring Flexible SSL works transparently).

The other solution is to use [Cloudflare's Origin CA](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218408028-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-Certificate-Other-) service to run SSL in Full (Strict) mode.